# How to fix source fields are not mapped?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool

I have seen a few errors like this but none of them seem to apply to me. I am receiving the error below when trying to migrate from 1.9.3.2 to 2.1.6

```
[2017-04-24 17:19:32][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: EAV Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec

Source fields are not mapped. Document: eav_attribute. Fields:is_visible_on_front,sorting_order,checkout_step,show_on_grid,store_ids,save_selected,parent_dropdown,include_pdf,apply_default,customer_groups,size_text,required_on_front_only,include_html_print_order
```

In the map.xml file I added this-

```
<ignore>
   <field>is_visible_on_front</field>
</ignore>
```

And changed the config file from map.xml.dist to map.xml

I got the same error. Instead of trying it in the map.xml file I tried the map-eav.xml file. Still got the same error. Am I doing this in the right files?

Edit:
I tweaked the map-eav.xml and got it to work. I needed to make it look like this- eav_attribute.is_visible_on_front by adding the table in front. My question now is how do you know which xml document the ignore tags need to be in?

Comment: Try adding them to map-eav.xml

Answer (score 2):

Let's try following code:

```
<ignore>
   <field>eav_attribute.is_visible_on_front</field>
</ignore>
```